# Passing a vector to constructor of a class

Tags: c++, constructor

**Note**: I have seen all the similar questions on this website, but I still could not make this work.

I made a class for astronomical coordinates and I am trying to overload the << operator to store user input in the class. The two coordinates (right ascension and declination) are vectors of doubles.

When I call the parametrised constructor, I get the following two errors: "call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type" and "no match for call to '(coordinates) (std::vector&, std::vector&)'".
It seems like I have to pass the vectors by reference, but I haven't managed to. How do I make it work?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class coordinates {
protected: 
    std::vector<double> right_ascension, declination; 
public:
    std::vector<double> zero_vector{(1,0)};
    coordinates(): right_ascension{zero_vector}, declination{zero_vector} {} // Default constructor
    coordinates(std::vector<double> ra, std::vector<double> dec) : right_ascension{ra}, declination{dec} {} // Paramterised constructor
    ~coordinates(){std::cout << "Calling coordinates destructor" << std::endl;}

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, coordinates &coords);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, coordinates &coord){    
    // Read imput from string stream "1.1 2.2 3.3; 4.4 5.5 6.6"
    std::string right_ascension;
    double hh, mm, sec;
    std::vector<double> ra, dec;
    
    // Read data
    std::stringstream ss("");
    std::getline(is, right_ascension, ';');
    ss.str("");
    ss << right_ascension; 
    ss >> hh >> mm >> sec;
    ra.push_back(hh);
    ra.push_back(mm);
    ra.push_back(sec);

    is >> hh >> mm >> sec;
    dec.push_back(hh);
    dec.push_back(mm);
    dec.push_back(sec);
    
    coord(ra, dec); // Here I get the two errors I mentioned
    return is;
}

int main() {
    coordinates coords;
    std::cout << "Input numbers (hh mm ss; hh ss mm)";
    std::cin >> coords;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `coord` is already an object. You cannot call the constructor on an already constructed object again

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number That makes sense, thank you. Would you make a temporary object and copy it to `coord` then?

Comment: why? You can assign to the members directly

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to create an object is:

```
coord = coordinates(ra, dec);
```

or

```
coord = coordinates{ra, dec};
```

(depending on your preferred style). This code constructs an object of type `coordinates` and then assigns it to the `coord` parameter.